# React studently only display white screen with 82 vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

Since last week, my react typescript website simply stop working. I really don't understand why, I barely touched it, I was busy with other things. Now when I do npm run start, it opens in with a white page without any error.

Strangely, it also start telling me that I have tons (around 80) of vulnerabilities of different levels, when before I had around 4.

I also have warning that looks like this when starting the website. Here only one, but they seems to be about react, webpack or babel packages.

```
../Playerz_serverless/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\client\utils\safeThis.js
* C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\playerz_serverless\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 9 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\Playerz_serverless\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\BERNARD\Desktop\playerz_serverless\node_modules\mini-create-react-context\dist\esm\index.js
```

What the weirdest about this is that is the whatever commits I roll back to, the problems are all still there when it was previously working fine.

I have tried deleting node_mudule, package-lock.json, yarn.lock but nothing worked.

I used to have a problem where there where two version of babel detected, but it seems like it went away, I am not sure how.

Thanks for any help, and if you need code snippets, let me know. I cannot think of any snippet useful as it was all working before.

Comment: Check the dependencies in your `package.json` file. If there are dependencies with the version starting with `~` it might mean that the minor version might be updated.

Comment: I found no ~ in the package.json file. Was worth a try thought.

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules, package-lock and yarn lock, then `npm install` and `npm audit` you can also try `npm audit fix` to fix them automatically.  But I feel like the issue is in the node modules.

Comment: Hey @BernardMeunier, sorry, I forgot to mention also `^`. 

`~version`: “Approximately equivalent to version”
`^version`: “Compatible with version”

Comment: After doing npm audit, I figure that most of the the vulnerabilities comes from postcss being version 7.13.0. I don't use this package myself, but it seems to be a dependency of react-scripts. Whenever I try to manually install a updated version, it does not do it, I don't know why.